# How extract multi words in string by vb.net

Tags: vb.net, html-parsing

```html
<tr class="sh"onclick="ii.ShowShareHolder('7358,IRO1GNBO0008')">
    <td>ghanisha sherkat-</td>
    <td><div class='ltr' title="141,933,691">142 M</div></td>
    <td>52.560</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td><div class=""/></td>
</tr>
```

We want output under items of above text:

```
ghanisha sherkat
141,933,691
52.560
0
```

My try:

```vb
Dim input as string="above text"

Dim c2 As String() = input.Split(New String() {"</td>"},StringSplitOptions.None)

Dim r As Integer

For r = 0 To c2.Length - 2
    MessageBox.Show(c2(r))
Next
```

other my try

```vb
   Dim sDelimStart As String = "<td>" 
                    Dim sDelimEnd As String = "</td>" 
                    Dim nIndexStart As Integer = input.IndexOf(sDelimStart) 
                    Dim nIndexEnd As Integer = input.IndexOf(sDelimEnd) 
                    
                         Res = Strings.Mid(input, nIndexStart + sDelimStart.Length + 1, nIndexEnd - nIndexStart - sDelimStart.Length)

                        MessageBox.Show(res)
```

by this way extract "ghanisha sherkat"

how extract other  items?

Now how continue it? thank you

Comment: no anybody help me?

Comment: You should avoid searching inside text or using regular expressions when parsing markup languages. Instead, if you have a parser available, use that to parse the markup and extract elements and attributes. I have provided two methods in my answer; one with using `XmlDocument` and some XPath, and one using regular expressions, which you should not be using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is not good to directly search a string or use Regular Expressions to parse markup code like HTML. You can instead use `XmlDocument` and parse HTML as XML using `<?xml...?>` tag.

### 1. Using `XmlDocument`

```
Dim input As String = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tr class="sh" onclick="ii.ShowShareHolder('7358,IRO1GNBO0008')">
    <td>ghanisha sherkat</td>
    <td><div class="ltr" title="141,933,691">142 M</div></td>
    <td>52.560</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td><div class=""/></td>
</tr>.ToString()

Dim doc As New XmlDocument
doc.LoadXml(input)

' Fetch all TDs inside TRs using XPath
Dim tds = doc.SelectNodes("/tr/td")

For Each item As XmlNode In tds
    ' If element id a DIV
    If item.FirstChild.Name = "div" Then
        ' Get the title attribute
        Dim titleAttr = item.FirstChild.Attributes("title")
        If Not titleAttr Is Nothing Then
            Console.WriteLine(titleAttr.Value)
        End If
    End If
    Console.WriteLine(item.InnerText())
Next
```

You can see a working example using `XmlDocument` at this [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mdNAz3).

### 2. Usign Regular Expressions (*not recommended*)

```
Dim input As String =
<tr class="sh" onclick="ii.ShowShareHolder('7358,IRO1GNBO0008')">
    <td>ghanisha sherkat</td>
    <td><div class="ltr" title="141,933,691">142 M</div></td>
    <td>52.560</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td><div class=""/></td>
</tr>.ToString()

' Extract all TDs
Dim tds = Regex.Matches(input, "<td[^>]*>\s*(.*?)\s*<\/td>")

For Each td In tds
    Dim content = td.Groups(1).ToString()
    ' Check if element id DIV
    If Regex.IsMatch(content, "^<div") Then
        ' Check if DIV has a title attribute
        Dim title = Regex.Match(content, "<div.*title=""(.*?)"">(.*)<\/div>")
        If title.Length > 0 Then
            ' Print the first group for title 141,933,691
            Console.WriteLine(title.Groups(1))
            ' Print the second group for element content 142 M
            Console.WriteLine(title.Groups(2))
        End If
    Else
        Console.WriteLine(td.Groups(1))
    End If
Next
```

You can see a working example using Regular Expressions at this [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sigV0l).

### Result

The result on both examples will be the same:

```
ghanisha sherkat
141,933,691
142 M
52.560
0
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex can make this job easier.

I'm assuming the values you want to capture are the ones directly inside a td tag or into a title attribute inside a td.

So you can use the following Regular Expression to capture all values that starts with td tag, may have or not a tag inside with a title attribute, then have or not a closing quote after the value, and ends with closing td tag.

```
    <td>(?:<.*title="")?([a-zA-Z0-9 \.,]*)""?.*\-?</td>
```

Here's the VB.Net code:

```
    Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

    Public Class Form1

        Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
            Dim input As String = "above text"

            Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(input, "<td>(?:<.*title="")?([a-zA-Z0-9 \.,]*)""?.*\-?</td>")

            ' Loop over matches.
            For Each m As Match In matches
                MessageBox.Show(m.Groups(1).Value)
            Next
        End Sub
    End Class
```